# How to delete the full row of a SQLite database by entering only a string value of a particular column?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using this method to get query for this string:

```
public void deletedata(){
    p=srt.split(",");

    DatabaseHandler dba=new DatabaseHandler(this);
    for(String s:p) {
        dba.removeSingleproduct(s);
    }
```

Database method is :

```
public boolean removeSingleproduct(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        return db.delete(tablename, productinserted + "=" + name, null) > 0;
    }
```

I want to delete only one row by calling database as product inserted can have two same value.

Please help guys.

Answer (score 1):

> Since you're deleting with a selectedValue `String`,
>   add a single quote before and after the name

```
return db.delete(tablename, productinserted + " = '" + name + "'", null) > 0;
```

> Or you can simplify your code.

```
public int removeSingleproduct(String name) {
    return getWritableDatabase().delete(tablename, productinserted + " = ?", new String[] { name });
}
```

> Return `int` - [the number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0 otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

Answer (score 0):

The following will use the name to locate all rows with the provided name but only delete the first according to it's rowid (unless WITHOUT ROWID has been specified [very likely not]).

```
public boolean removeSingleproduct(String name) {
    boolean rv = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor csr = db.query(tablename,new String[]{"rowid AS dltid"},productinserted + "=?",new String[]{name},null,null,null);
    if(csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = db.delete(tablename,"rowid=?",new String[]{Long.toString(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("dltid")))}) > 0;
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

If you wanted to ensure that a row was only deleted if multiple rows with the same **productinserted** name existed, then you could simply change

```
    if(csr.moveToFirst()) { ........
```

to

```
    if(csr.moveToFirst() && csr.getCount() > 1) { .......
```

Note! `csr.moveToLast()` could be used instead of `csr.moveToFirst()` it would probably then delete the newest addition rather than probably deleting the oldest addition.

If you think

> but I haven't defined a column called rowid

then :-

> Except for WITHOUT ROWID tables, all rows within SQLite tables have a
>   64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its
>   table. This integer is usually called the "rowid". The rowid value can
>   be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid",
>   "oid", or "*rowid*" in place of a column name. If a table contains a
>   user defined column named "rowid", "oid" or "*rowid*", then that name
>   always refers the explicitly declared column and cannot be used to
>   retrieve the integer rowid value.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)